# Google sheets formatting in android webview

Tags: android, webview, kotlin, google-sheets-api

I want to show a google sheet in an android webview, which I thought would be fairly straightforward.   I can't get it to format correctly.  Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="com.example.grant.gradechaser.fragment.ClimbListFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/AppTheme.myListTitle"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="10 unsynced climbs"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webview.loadUrl("my sheets url here")

    webview.refreshDrawableState()
}
```

Here's what it ends up looking like on my phone, just shows the individual sheets titles but none of the content.  Other websites look fine

[image: weird formatting]

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, just needed to enable javascript

```
webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```